# Move string of each line into a specific position

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how can I move string of each line into a specific position ?

Example :

```
CXTYPMORDER TEXT IS 'Type of order' , 
CXNUMORD TEXT IS 'Number of order' , 
CXCC TEXT IS 'Code of order' , 
CXDAY TEXT IS 'Day of order' , 
CXMONTH TEXT IS 'Month of order' ,
```

Wanted result :

```
CXTYPMORDER   TEXT IS 'Type of order' , 
CXNUMORD      TEXT IS 'Number of order' , 
CXCC          TEXT IS 'Code of order' , 
CXDAY         TEXT IS 'Day of order' , 
CXMONTH       TEXT IS 'Month of order' ,
```

EDIT 1 :

I've tryed this :

```
    $newstreamreader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("N:\TEMP\TEST\TEST.txt")
    $newstreamwriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("N:\TEMP\TEST\TEST_New.txt")
    $eachlinenumber = 1
    $position = 0
    $numberofspace = 0
    
    while (($readeachline =$newstreamreader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
        if($readeachline -match "^(\S+) TEXT IS '([^']+)'"){
            $position = $readeachline.IndexOf("TEXT IS")
            $numberofspace = 15-$position
            $newstring = $readeachline.Insert($position, " " * $numberofspace)
            $newstreamwriter.WriteLine($newstring)
        }
        $eachlinenumber++
    }

$newstreamwriter.Close()
```

EDIT 2 :

It works now :)
Thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.  ... and why (whatfor) you want to do this? The re might be a better way.  ;-)

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie in PowerShell, so I have no idea on how to do it. It's juste for to read easily a large file (74000 lines). It's a description of each Table in a Database.

Comment: It is beyond the scope of SO to teach you a complex technology like Powershell. You will have to learn the basics first. And SO is not a free coding service. Have you tried to search for it? There are probably thousands of examples out there of how to manipulate strings with Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `-match` regex operator to match and capture the relevant parts of each line, then construct an object that can easily be formatted for ease of readability:

```
# Use Get-Content to read the file line by line
$Descriptions = Get-Content path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
  # Check if current line is what we're looking for:
  if($_ -match "^(\S+) TEXT IS '([^']+)'"){
    # Extract capture group values
    $EntryName = $Matches[1]
    $Description = $Matches[2]

    # Create a new object with the extracted values
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Name = $EntryName
      Description = $Description
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use `Format-Table` to make it nice an readable:

```
PS C:\> $Descriptions |Format-Table -AutoSize

Name        Description
----        -----------
CXTYPMORDER Type of order
CXNUMORD    Number of order
CXCC        Code of order
CXDAY       Day of order
CXMONTH     Month of order
```

---

The regular expression pattern used above (`^(\S+) TEXT IS '([^']+)'`) describes:

```
^           # Start of string
(           # Start capture group
\S+         # 1 or more non-whitespace characters
)           # End capture group
 TEXT IS '  # Literal string ` TEXT IS '
(           # Start capture group
[^']+       # 1 or more characters that aren't single-quotes
)           # End capture group
'           # Literal single-quote
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to do, it's to write the changes into the file. I'll edit my question to show you what I have found.

Comment: @SalahK. You need to call `Close()` on the stream writer after you're done, this will flush its buffers and release the file handle (after which you'll see the data written)

Answer (score 0):

`$newstreamreader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("N:\TEMP\TEST\TEST.txt")
$newstreamwriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("N:\TEMP\TEST\TEST_New.txt")
$eachlinenumber = 1
$position = 0
$numberofspace = 0
while (($readeachline =$newstreamreader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
    if($readeachline -match "^(\S+) TEXT IS '([^']+)'"){
        $position = $readeachline.IndexOf("TEXT IS")
        $numberofspace = 15-$position
        $newstring = $readeachline.Insert($position, " " * $numberofspace)
        $newstreamwriter.WriteLine($newstring)
    }
    $eachlinenumber++
}
$newstreamwriter.Close()`